# Can I escape html tags within a class (recreate the xmp tag)?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, markdown, xmp

A couple ways to think of this question. Decide for yourself which is most useful for you…

- Can javascript recreate the deprecated <xmp> tag with an "xmp" class?
- Can we mimic SO's markdown processor's escaping tags within inline code?
- (metaSO, I admit) How does SO's md processor escape tags in inline code?
- Can we escape < in markdown code blocks embedded in HTML?

The goal: a class that escapes `<`, allowing that class to contain the text <html>, <body>, <head>, <script>, <style>, <body>, and any other tags that don't belong inside <body> or are processed specially, *without* processing them specially.

<xmp> achieved this (and actually continues to - deprecated but still browser-supported): `<xmp><body></xmp>` was like `&lt;body&gt;`. SO's markdown processor achieves this *in inline code*: to display `<body>` just write `<body>` (which itself is \`&lt;body>\` and *cannot* be included in an SO code block… I'm not the only one who could use this ;)

My solution so far —replacing all `<` with `&lt;`— takes care of the less-special HTML tags (is there a name for these within-<body> static content tags? <div>, <code>, <span>, etc), but the "special" tags still have to be started with &lt; instead of <

```
Javascript:
xmps = document.getElementsByClassName('xmp');
for (var i = 0; i < xmps.length; i++) {
    var xmp = xmp.item(i);
    var newhtml = xmp.innerHTML.replace(/\&gt;/g,"\>").replace(/\&lt;/g,"\<");
    xmp.innerHTML = newhtml;
    }
```

With that I can write `<div class="xmp">&lt;body></div>`.

What will allow

`<div class="xmp"><body></div>`?

or how about?

```
<div class="xmp">
    <body>
    &/div>
</div>
```

The details of my project might matter: There'll be markdown in `class="xmp"` so we need to be careful with line-initial `>`s. There is no user input, so security isn't(?) an issue. I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create the functionality of the `xmp` with JavaScript, because the functionality is about HTML parsing. And the element has already been parsed by the browser when it JavaScript can get her hands on it.

On the other hand, I don’t see any need for that. As far as I know, `xmp` is supported by all browsers, and HTML5 CR requires that support be retained and that new browsers implement it too. It also says that authors must not use it, but this doesn’t mean `xmp` wouldn’t work.

Comment: It's true that `xmp` is still browser-supported, so if you want to keep using it I guess you can. Still, there isn't exactly a promise of longevity, and I personally would not use it.

The fact remains that Pagedown (SO's markdown parser) manages to see  \`&lt;body>\` as \`'s around some characters rather than &lt;body> with some characters around it, a case of \` escaping angle brackets. So some &amp;lt; trick -or something- _is_ possible.