# How to get html to display without being parsed

Tags: html, html-parsing

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<code>

//my html which will just be pasted in and not parsed, for people to read/copy, goes here
<h1>hello world</h1>

<code>
```

I know that i can use a code tag and inside it, a script tag with `type="text/plain"` and `display: block;` it in css, but it is not responsive and it doesnt look good.

I looked online but couldnt really find anything to solve this issue.

I just want a place where I can paste my HTML, CSS or JS for display purposes and for it to be unparsed and styleable and responsive.

Anyone got any idea of the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<xmp>` tag around your code. It is frowned upon and could be deprecated in the future, but browsers still support it and will interpret everything as raw HTML and display it accordingly. See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) as well as a fuller explanations on [SO: Show source code without XMP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156549/show-source-code-without-xmp-tag). Without `xmp`, you'll need to escape all `<` and `>` in a `pre` or `code` tag.